# Failed to open Stream, no such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-artisan

I recently started using the Laravel framework and i set up a little workspace for me to work in. I setup a Xubuntu client at home that runs a Apache server from which i program and host my Laravel instance from. Now recently I've run into a little bit of a problem. I was following a tutorial series and everything went fine, the next day however i run into this error http://puu.sh/nh5vQ/8ae11c52ab.png
Both from opening the /var/www/html/test/public directory in apache2 from my webbrowser or from running php artisan and actually hosting the laravel instance.

So the first thing that came to mind was permissions, but the permissions for the public folder are fine, It should be able to read or execute as any program. http://puu.sh/nh5Ho/06e061a056.png

Mostly other posts can reference to a bit of code where they specified the wrong filepath. What i find odd is that when i open my hosted instance of apache server in my webbrowser, where you can technically browse all the files in the hosted directory it is there in the list, but when i click it it pops up with that same error.

I checked if all the files that the server is trying to acces exist, and they do exist and i made no typo's.

I'm going to continue on looking and i shall post the solution as soon as i find one, though I'm hoping you guys have an idea since I've been looking for about 2 days to find a solution.

Thanks for your time

Comment: shouldn't the files be owned by www-data:www-data instead of joris:joris?

Comment: Would that make any difference? If the permissions for "Other users" are r-x then it should be able to acces the files properly anyway right?

Comment: @Th3Alchemist I changed the ownership of all the files in the folder to www-data and now i get a server error 500 when opening the public folder. http://puu.sh/nh8V5/94a8e40cda.png I also added the joris user to the www-data group

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this kind of problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021

Answer (score 0):

I Decided I'd have to start a new Laravel project to fix this without making a chaoticly configured project.